# unable to parse timetstamp correctly on ELK 5.4

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

I am using the last ELK stack (5.4.0). I am parsing some apache log.
All is OK with elasticsearch 2.4.5 and kibana 4.6.4

**OK version**

```
apache 173.252.115.89 - - [29/May/2017:09:59:13 +0200] "GET /fr/fia/nodes.rss HTTP/1.1" 200 19384 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1" "-" 756752 "*/*" monsite.com
```

is perfectly entered in elasticsearch with the following grok conf

```
grok {
          match => { "message" => "%{WORD:program} %{COMBINEDAPACHELOG} \"((?<x_forwarded_for>%{IP:xff_clientip}.*)|-)\" %{NUMBER:request_time:float} %{QUOTEDSTRING:accept} %{IPORHOST:targethost}"}
        }
        date {
           match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
        }
```

with the following kibana conf
[image]

**Problem**

With ELK 5.4, I have exactly the same message (coming from a duplicate rabbitmq queue), the same logstash conf and a 'fresh install' but I get

elasticsearch log

```
[2017-05-29T10:17:58,498][DEBUG][o.e.a.b.TransportShardBulkAction] [srv-elk-01] [logstash-2017.05.29][1] failed to execute bulk item (index) BulkShardRequest [[logstash-2017.05.29][1]] containing
 [16] requests
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [timestamp]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:298) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
...
at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DateFieldMapper.parseCreateField(DateFieldMapper.java:468) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldMapper.parse(FieldMapper.java:287) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        ... 40 more
```

logstash log

```
[2017-05-29T10:17:58,503][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Failed action. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"logstash-2017.05.29", :_type=>"syslog", :_routing=>nil}, 2017-05-29T08:17:57.000Z 212.95.67.139 apache 212.95.70.118 - - [29/May/2017:10:17:57 +0200] "GET /de/tag/opera HTTP/1.1" 200 8948 "-" "TurnitinBot (https://turnitin.com/robot/crawlerinfo.html)" "199.47.87.143, 199.47.87.143" 784504 "text/*,application/*" monsite.com], :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-2017.05.29", "_type"=>"syslog", "_id"=>"AVxTSHzL1K94bfQE3eaM", "status"=>400, "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to parse [timestamp]", "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_argument_exception", "reason"=>"Invalid format: \"29/May/2017:10:17:57 +0200\" is malformed at \"/May/2017:10:17:57 +0200\""}}}}}
```

My kibana conf is
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well the recent version of Kibana does not use timestamp field it is deprecated.
Use "date" in your logstash conf file.
For more details look here:
[timestamp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#_literal__timestamp_literal_and_literal__ttl_literal)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove timestamp as below

```
date {
           match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
           remove_field => ["timestamp"]
        }
```

and then it's all OK